# display a list of images in the options of an android application

Tags: android, android-optionsmenu

I'm working on an application where I want to give the user the option of being able to select an image from a list in the options menu. Kind of like how you can select the ringtone of your phone, but with images instead.

I can display the list of images in a spinner in my main activity, but I have no idea how to translate that onto the preferences screen. Is it possible to have a spinner on the preferences screen?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by the options menu?

Comment: within the preferences.xml file. So the flow would be like: Options> default image> image list.

Comment: what preferences.xml file? And what Options? What process are you describing?

Comment: I'm following the example I found here : http://www.kaloer.com/android-preferences . What I want to do is take the list preference and display images instead of Number 1, Number 2, etc

Comment: Ah! ok... now it makes sense...

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to make a custom adapter that you hand to the Spinner. Rather than giving it an adapter filled with Strings (which is what you're doing now) you're going to give it an adapter filled with ImageViews.

Here's a good example...
[Simple Adapter problem, Text + Image in spinner. Java, Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3688925/simple-adapter-problem-text-image-in-spinner-java-android)

Comment: I'm doing that in my main activity. Here's the code:            `code`  Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        mySpinner.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.activity_main, imageNames));`code`                         I'm really unclear on how to adapt that to my preferences screen. and how are you inserting line breaks in your comments?